# Check input data and its sequence by MySQL

Tags: javascript, php

i want a drag and drop question and its options in  to be fetched from mysql table and make all options in a correct sequence. how to check my sequence to table correct sequence. i have this drag and drop code.

---

in this example we know correct sequence is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. when we will drag all in correct order and submit it, how we match submitted sequence with correct sequence automatically. this is a kind of education test game.

---

```
<style>
  body {
    font-family: arial;
    background: rgb(242, 244, 246);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }

  h3 {
    color: rgb(199, 204, 209);
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #elements-container {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .draggable-element {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: move;
  }

  .drag-list {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .drag-list > li {
    list-style: none;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .drag-list .title {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .drag-list .drag-area {
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgb(158, 211, 179);
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    cursor: move;
  }

  .code {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
    width: 600px;
    margin: 22px auto;
    position: relative;
  }

  .code::before {
    content: 'Code';
    background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
    width: 96%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px 2%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }

  .code pre {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0 13px;
    font-size: 1em;
  }

</style>
```

---

```
    <section class="showcase showcase-2">
      <h3>Example 2</h3>
      <ul class="drag-list">
        <li><span class="title">list 6</span><span class="drag-area"></span></li>
        <li><span class="title">list 4</span><span class="drag-area"></span></li>
        <li><span class="title">list 5</span><span class="drag-area"></span></li>
        <li><span class="title">list 1</span><span class="drag-area"></span></li>
        <li><span class="title">list 3</span><span class="drag-area"></span></li>
        <li><span class="title">list 2</span><span class="drag-area"></span></li>
        <li><span class="title">list 7</span><span class="drag-area"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="code">
      <pre>
$('li').arrangeable({dragSelector: '.drag-area'});
      </pre>
    </section>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="drag-arrange.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          $('.draggable-element').arrangeable();
          $('li').arrangeable({dragSelector: '.drag-area'});
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: the php part is missing

Comment: we can fetch those ul list options by mysql query

Comment: also in what manner i can insert my correct sequence in table to be matched from submitted sequence

Comment: So you have a order or sequence column in your database?

Comment: use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: like i have a cell of correct sequence in a row of every question like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. i have to match this sequence with my submitted sequence in html form

Comment: Are you using a library for this or you have coded it all yourself?

Comment: no library. just a simple code in js

Comment: is any help ???

Comment: Posted the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using javaScript like this:

First, you need to take the reference of the question's id somewhere. To make it simple just assign it to the id attribute of your `<li>` tag.

```
var sort_order = [];

jQuery('.drag-list li').each(function(index){
     sort_order[index] = this.id;
});
```

Now, the `sort_order` will have your question ids along with their sequence.

Hope you get the logic. Now you can tweak it according to your requirements.

Comment: @nikk you want to know the order of the options after sorting them using drag(JS). Right?

Comment: ya we can say i want to store option sequence in a input box on comma separated. this input box sequence i can match to table value

Comment: can u assist me?

Answer (score 0):

i got this working. but how to apply this for multiple questions fetching automatically from database.

---

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
$( "#savebutton" ).click(function() { LISTOBJ.saveList(); });
});

var LISTOBJ = {
    saveList: function() {
        var listCSV = "";
        $( "#sortable li" ).each(function() {
            if (listCSV === "") {
                listCSV = $(this).val();
            } else {
                listCSV += "," + $(this).val();
            }
            $("#output").text(listCSV);
            $("#hiddenListInput").val(listCSV);
            //$("#listsaveform").submit();
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
 <ul id="sortable">
  <li value="1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li value="2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li value="3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>

</ul>
<input type="button" id="savebutton" value="save"/>
<div id="output"></div>
<form id="listsaveform" method="POST" action="script.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="list" id="hiddenListInput" />
</form>
```